# Based on morphology alone, what type of claw does the Tyrannosaur have?

Tags: morphology, dinosaurs

I understand that the exact use of Tyrannosaur Rex's claw is a mystery, or at least debated. I also understand that claws can be used for a variety of different purposes, selective pressure adapts their morphological to be better optimized for certain tasks. Some are used for hunting and killing, like large cats' claws, some are used for digging, like bear's claws, while others are used for climbing, like squirrel's claws.

My question is, all other clues and bits of information about if and how T. Rex might have used its arms, what 'type' of claws did it possess? I'm not asking, in this question, about its arm, the arm's musculature, its mouth or jaw, or about any of the rest of the animal. Based on the morphology of the claw alone, and comparing it to known uses of similarly shaped claws, what types of tasks were the claws geared towards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately they have fairly generic claws, they are not specialized enough to point to a use. They are curved enough to be used to grasp something but that is true for their ancestral line too so there is no sign of a specific directional selection.